# How to open SDCARD of android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-sdcard

Hi all i was trying to upload a pdf file to my php server script i pdf file is there on android mobile it will be on sd card only so i want to open sd card of android device using phonegap via javascript.

Comment: See i did an image uploading for that i used navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY fuction to open gallery like wise i need to open sdcard... how will i do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
U can easily do that its very easy

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccessUpload, fail);

    function onFileSystemSuccessUpload(fileSystem) {
     // get directory entry through root and access all the folders
             var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();

    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(successReader,fail); 

          }

      function successReader(entries) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
           //alert(entries[i].name);
           if(entries[i].isDirectory==true)
           {
             var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
            directoryReaderIn.readEntries(successReader,fail); 

           }

            if(entries[i].isFile==true)
             {
          entries[i].file(uploadFile, fail);
           }
        }
    }; 

 function uploadFile(file) {
var target=""; //the url to upload on server
     var ft = new FileTransfer(),path = "file://"+ file.fullPath,name = file.name;
                ft.upload(path, target, win, fail, { fileName: name });
               // var ft = new FileTransfer();
              //ft.upload(file.fullPath, target, win, fail, options);


            function win(r) {
                alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
               alert("Response = " + r.response);
                alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            }
}
```

Comment: so r u saying window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccessUpload, fail); this will open sdcard of android.

Comment: U will get the filesystem access. Then with var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader(); u will get the access to the directory entry object and with that access to all the folders in the device filesytem. I have done that.

Comment: Please can u post a sample...i tried to list the content only not getting the access...

Comment: In the SuccessReader function i posted above in the for loop do alert(entries[i].name); remove everything u will start getting the names of directory and files on ur device file system. Remove everything else. Dude u need to go through phone gap file api doc to need to understand this. BTW vote for the post :P

Comment: So SuccessReader function is enough for opening sd card path right so after i can click and upload any file...

Comment: Can you tell how to call this method or what value should be given to filesystem in that method...

Comment: O yes suucess reader is enough..And filesystem.root is itself an directory object look at the function onFileSystemSuccessUpload(fileSystem) in that fileSystem.root.createReader();
creates the reader. Enjoy!!

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

this opens up options where u can choose files and selecting one will give u the name and path of the file in the successFn

Comment: i need to upload a .pdf file so i need to open sdcard only how could i open

Comment: no option to open sdcard only. the user will have to navigate to the sd card folder in the file chooser that comes

Comment: see i have a button if i press the button it has to navigate to sdcard of mobile...after that user can select his file and upload....

Comment: u'll have to write your own phonegap plugin for that. for opening just the sd card contents