# Access sd card in android for uploading a file to my php server using phonegap

Tags: file-upload, cordova, android-sdcard

I want to go to select a file from sdcard and upload it to server. is it possible to access the sdcard in android via phonegap as how we are picking a image from gallery and uploading. I went through samples but all are specifying the file name also like eg: mnt/sdcard/read.txt. But i want to goto only sdcard so that user can select his own file is it possible to do.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940667/how-to-open-sdcard-of-android-using-phonegap/9942626#9942626  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
U can easily do that its very easy

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccessUpload, fail);

    function onFileSystemSuccessUpload(fileSystem) {
     // get directory entry through root and access all the folders
             var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();

    // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
    directoryReader.readEntries(successReader,fail); 

          }

      function successReader(entries) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
           //alert(entries[i].name);
           if(entries[i].isDirectory==true)
           {
             var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
            directoryReaderIn.readEntries(successReader,fail); 

           }

            if(entries[i].isFile==true)
             {
          entries[i].file(uploadFile, fail);
           }
        }
    }; 

 function uploadFile(file) {
var target=""; //the url to upload on server
     var ft = new FileTransfer(),path = "file://"+ file.fullPath,name = file.name;
                ft.upload(path, target, win, fail, { fileName: name });
               // var ft = new FileTransfer();
              //ft.upload(file.fullPath, target, win, fail, options);


            function win(r) {
                alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
               alert("Response = " + r.response);
                alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            }
}
```

Comment: @Guru how to execute this because i tried this nothing happened...can u post ur html...

Comment: It will start uploading in the background. This code will scan through the complete file system and keep uploading to the php server in the background. Instead first check whether its working put this in ur index.html and function successReader(entries) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
           alert(entries[i].name);
        
       
        }
    };

Comment: u should see the name of the folders in the file system if everything is working fine.

Comment: i tried in alert it is giving all the files inside the sd card... but i wanted to view the sdcard and select any file from it and upload it to a server. is it possible or only we can view the contents......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045065/trying-to-open-android-sd-card-using-html-javascript-and-phonegap can u check this cide in this way also i tried nothing happening...

Comment: Remove the alert. Now check whether the type is of "file" using if(entries[i].isFile==true) and then use the upload part in upload function check the name using file.name or path using file.fullPAth then upload the particular file. In "target" variable of upload specify the path of your php server.

Comment: @user1051599 hi have you found solution for your problem?If so can you please share with me? I have same issue and i really need a help.I posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776877/browse-function-in-android-using-phonegap