# Programmatically upload a file from SD Card to a remote server using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have been trying to upload a (zip) file to a remote server programmatically using **Phonegap** in **Android** mobile. I have tried the [FileAPI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) documentation and the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953483/access-sd-card-in-android-for-uploading-a-file-to-my-php-server-using-phonegap). But it doesn't seem to work. However I could successfully upload an image (using the camera and navigator) as described in the examples.

I have a file `test.zip` in a folder `test` in the **SD Card**. I need to upload this file to a remote server.

Any help regarding this would be great.

Comment: Is it bcoz of the wrong URI ? IS there a way to get the correct URI for the SD Card ? Tried with 'file:///test/test.zip' and 'content://media/external/test/test.zip'

Comment: The FileAPI pointed out by you says that in case of an error. the error will be reported in error callback with FileTransferError object. What does that object say?

Comment: Getting an error "Error in error callback: FileTransfer3 = ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment". But I can succesfully upload an image, if FILEURI  given as "content://media/external/images/media/963". I assume something wrong with my zip fileURI ?

Comment: I haven't used Phonegap myself, but to me it seems that there is an error in the error callback function itself. Since the image is uploaded successfully, the error callback is never called then. In case of zip file upload there is an error but is currently hidden behind the error in error callback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working, here is the code that I used

```
uploadFile('test.zip', 'Test', 'multipart/x-zip');

function uploadFile(fileName, dirName, fileMime) {

    var win = function(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    };

    var fail = function(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    };

    var fileURI;

    var gotFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(dirName, {
            create : false
        }, function(dataDir) {

            fileURI = dataDir.fullPath;
            fileURI = fileURI + '/' + fileName;

            alert(fileURI);

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = fileMime;

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(fileURI,

                    // Enter the server url
                    "http://example.com/upload.php", win,
                    fail, options);

        }, dirFail);

    };

    // file system fail
    var fsFail = function(error) {
        alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);

    };

    // get file system to copy or move image file to
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem,
            fsFail);

    var dirFail = function(error) {
        alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);

    };
}
```