# How to Upload audio from sd-card to server in android

Tags: java, android, file, file-upload, fileoutputstream

I am trying to upload audio file from particular folder of SD-Card to server. but when i try to do that i am getting following error.

`error: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`

and my full logcat is as below.

```
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164): error: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/AudioRecorder: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.doAudioFileUpload(Record_AudioPG.java:295)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.stopRecording(Record_AudioPG.java:271)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.access$0(Record_AudioPG.java:265)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG$4.onClick(Record_AudioPG.java:124)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:437)
01-23 12:44:18.920: E/Debug(6164):  ... 16 more
```

and one more logcat below this is

```
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.doAudioFileUpload(Record_AudioPG.java:344)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.stopRecording(Record_AudioPG.java:271)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG.access$0(Record_AudioPG.java:265)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at iqualtech.skirr.Record_AudioPG$4.onClick(Record_AudioPG.java:124)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-23 12:44:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(6164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My Code**

```
private void doAudioFileUpload() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/AudioRecorder/";

        System.out.println("Inside of doupload nd path is === "
                + existingFileName);

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        String urlString = "http://link to server/folder-name/upload_audio.php";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    existingFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't find the file path so returning null value!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953483/access-sd-card-in-android-for-uploading-a-file-to-my-php-server-using-phonegap May be this will help you i think

Comment: @mrfarts, that code is using phonegap i have not used that. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: "/AudioRecorder/" is a Directory and you are using it as file name, i guess you need to put your file name there as well like "/AudioRecorder/audio.mp3" etc

Comment: But i want to upload all the file of folder AudioRecorder. say this folder contains more than 20 files.

Answer (score 2):

The log message is clear, you are trying to upload a directory, not a file :

```
String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/AudioRecorder/"
```

/AudioRecorder/ is not an audio file.You should perhaps append  the audio filename at the end.

If you have to upload all the files in the dir, then think about doing that inside an (Intent)service.

1. Add the filename as parameter to your method :
2. In your activity, Loop into the files list, and for each file :

   ```
   for(String filename : filesList ){

                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadIntentService.class);
                   Bundle params = new Bundle();
                   params.putString(UploadIntentService.KEY_FILE_NAME, filename);
                   activity.startService(intent);
   }
   ```
3. The Service :

   ```
   public class UploadIntentService extends IntentService {

   public static final String KEY_FILE_NAME= "filename";
   public UploadIntentService() {
       super("UploadIntentService");
               }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 
   String filename = intent.getBundle().getStringExtra(UploadIntentService.KEY_FILE_NAME);      

   doAudioFileUpload(filename);
          }

      private void doAudioFileUpload(String filename) {
       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       DataOutputStream dos = null;
       DataInputStream inStream = null;
       String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               .getPath() + "/AudioRecorder/"+filename;

       System.out.println("Inside of doupload nd path is === "
               + existingFileName);

       String lineEnd = "\r\n";
       String twoHyphens = "--";
       String boundary = "*****";
       int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
       byte[] buffer;
       int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
       String urlString = "http://link to server/folder-name/upload_audio.php";
       try {
           // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
           FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                   existingFileName));
           // open a URL connection to the Servlet
           URL url = new URL(urlString);
           // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
           conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           // Allow Inputs
           conn.setDoInput(true);
           // Allow Outputs
           conn.setDoOutput(true);
           // Don't use a cached copy.
           conn.setUseCaches(false);
           // Use a post method.
           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                   "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
           dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
           dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                   + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
           dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
           // create a buffer of maximum size
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
           // read file and write it into form...
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           while (bytesRead > 0) {
               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           }
           // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
           dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
           dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
           // close streams
           Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
           fileInputStream.close();
           dos.flush();
           dos.close();
       } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
           Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
           Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
       }
       // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
       try {
           inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
           String str;

           while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
               Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
           }
           inStream.close();

       } catch (IOException ioex) {
           Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
       }
   }
   ```

   Hope it helps

**PS: Not tested code.**

Comment: Yeah true but i want to upload all the files which is present inside AudioRecorder folder so how can i achieve this.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do this. Please post any code snippet or example if you have. This will be great help from your side.

Comment: okey, use IntentService class to upload sequentially the files.