# Trying to open Android SD card using HTML, Javascript and Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, android-sdcard

I am trying to open the SD card and upload a file in Android using Phonegap. Below is the code where I am appending the SD card content to my HTML, but nothing is displaying. I am using `cordova.js`, `jquery1.7.1.js`. Below is my code:

My Javascript:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    getFileSystem();
}

function getFileSystem() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function(fileSystem) { // success get file system
            root = fileSystem.root;
            listDir(root);
        }, 
        function(evt) { // error get file system
            console.log("File System Error: "+evt.target.error.code);
        }
    );
}

function listDir(directoryEntry) {
    if (!directoryEntry.isDirectory) 
        console.log('listDir incorrect type');

    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); // show loading message

    currentDir = directoryEntry; // set current directory
    directoryEntry.getParent(
        function(par) { // success get parent
            parentDir = par; // set parent directory
            if ((parentDir.name == 'sdcard' && currentDir.name != 'sdcard') || parentDir.name != 'sdcard') 
                $('#backBtn').show();
        }, 
        function(error) { // error get parent
            console.log('Get parent error: ' + error.code);
        }
    );

    var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(
        function(entries) {
            var dirContent = $('#dirContent');
            dirContent.empty();

            var dirArr = new Array();
            var fileArr = new Array();
            for (var i=0; i < entries.length; ++i) { // sort entries
                var entry = entries[i];
                if (entry.isDirectory && entry.name[0] != '.') 
                    dirArr.push(entry);
                else if (entry.isFile && entry.name[0] != '.') 
                    fileArr.push(entry);
            }

            var sortedArr = dirArr.concat(fileArr); // sorted entries
            var uiBlock = ['a','b','c','d'];

            for (var i=0; i < sortedArr.length; ++i) { // show directories
                var entry = sortedArr[i];
                var blockLetter = uiBlock[i%4];
                //console.log(entry.name);
                if (entry.isDirectory)
                    dirContent.append('<div class="ui-block-' + blockLetter + '"><div class="folder"><p>' + entry.name + '</p></div></div>');
                else if (entry.isFile)
                    dirContent.append('<div class="ui-block-' + blockLetter + '"><div class="file"><p>' + entry.name + '</p></div></div>');
            }
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // hide loading message
        }, 
        function(error) {
            console.log('listDir readEntries error: ' + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look in the Cordova API Documents? I Tried this sample code and it worked just fine. [Link to API and the sample code](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem)

Comment: I tried that also sd card is not opening. I dont need to access the file i need to access sd card and select file my self to upload...

Comment: Could this be something for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940667/how-to-open-sdcard-of-android-using-phonegap