# Is browsing in phone memory of android possible using phoengap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, file-upload

I want to upload a file which may be a .doc or .pdf or .jpeg or anything. I want to have a browse function which on click opens all files and folders existing in my android mobile or tablet and then i select a file from those and upload it.I've seen many examples but all i've seen are for uploading a pic from gallery.Can anyone please help me how to get browse function in android using phonegap.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader)

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray I've seen this plugin and this is also for image upload and i think it has no function for browse i feel.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. If there is pre-built component I am afraid you will have to use the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can look at this solution this can help you solve your problem.

[Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940667/how-to-open-sdcard-of-android-using-phonegap)

Comment: hi thanks for response yah i've seen that link previously but i am not able to implement it can u please show me full code of that code snippet if possible?