# Phonegap media src filepath for local files

Tags: cordova

I have a audiofile with the filePath :

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/myrecording.mp3
```

I tried to set that als src to play this audio-file. PG says it'd be undefined with code: 1.

How can I playback songs from its filePath?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this API's

- [Phonegap Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media)
- [Phonegap File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

Be aware that might be some restrictions for accessing external files

Comment: Yes, I know the API. 
src: A URI containing the audio content. (DOMString)
It says nothing about how to point local files.
The examples are only about files located on the internet.

Comment: Oh, I took a look ath the AudioPlayer.java implementation. The recorded audio uses file:// .. only two forwards ... I'm gonna try that out.

Comment: Maybe this will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940667/how-to-open-sdcard-of-android-using-phonegap)